# Pandas Replace Values with Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a data frame with the below structure:

```
        Ranges  Relative_17-Aug  Relative_17-Sep  Relative_17-Oct
0   (0.0, 0.1]  1372             1583             1214
1   (0.1, 0.2]  440              337              648
2   (0.2, 0.3]  111              51               105
3   (0.3, 0.4]  33               10               19
4   (0.4, 0.5]  16               4                9
5   (0.5, 0.6]  7                7                1
6   (0.6, 0.7]  4                3                0
7   (0.7, 0.8]  5                1                0
8   (0.8, 0.9]  2                3                0
9   (0.9, 1.0]  2                0                1
10  (1.0, 2.0]  6                0                2
```

I am trying to replace column ranges with a dictionary using the below code but it is not working, any hints if I am doing something wrong:

```
mydict= {"(0.0, 0.1]":"<=10%","(0.1, 0.2]":">10% and <20%","(0.2, 0.3]":">20% and <30%", "(0.3, 0.4]":">30% and <40%", "(0.4, 0.5]":">40% and <50%", "(0.5, 0.6]":">50% and <60%", "(0.6, 0.7]":">60% and <70%", "(0.7, 0.8]":">70% and <80%", "(0.8, 0.9]":">80% and <90%", "(0.9, 1.0]":">90% and <100%", "(1.0, 2.0]":">100%"}
t_df["Ranges"].replace(mydict,inplace=True)
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get column `Ranges` ?

Comment: Perhaps casting might help `t_df["Ranges"].astype(str).replace(mydict,inplace=True)`

Comment: What about using map method to use the value from the dict.?

Comment: I got ranges by using groupby
`ranges = [0,.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90,1.0,2.0]
`df_relative.groupby(pd.cut(df_relative["Relative_"+str(month)], ranges)).count()

Comment: I have put my full code on pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/2MqRZ68r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is best use parameter `labels` in time of create `Ranges` column in [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
labels = ['<=10%','>10% and <20%', ...]
#change by your bins
bins = [0,0.1,0.2...]
t_df['Ranges'] = pd.cut(t_df['col'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

If not possible, cast to string should help as suggest @Dark in comments, for better performance use `map`:

```
t_df["Ranges"] = t_df["Ranges"].astype(str).map(mydict)
```

Comment: Jezrael above tip works but I am still wondering why replace is not working. I used labels in pd.cut and output is as I required. Thanks

Comment: @RehanAzher - there is problem it is new `IntervalIndex`, so possible solution is cast to `string`s. But `cut` + `labels` is better solution.

Comment: Yes, `cut` + `label` is better solution.

Comment: Delima how to accept both as solution , both are working :)

Answer (score 2):

By using `map` function this can be achieved easily and in a straight forward manner as shown below..

```
mydict= {"(0.0, 0.1]":"<=10%","(0.1, 0.2]":">10% and <20%","(0.2, 0.3]":">20% and <30%", "(0.3, 0.4]":">30% and <40%", "(0.4, 0.5]":">40% and <50%", "(0.5, 0.6]":">50% and <60%", "(0.6, 0.7]":">60% and <70%", "(0.7, 0.8]":">70% and <80%", "(0.8, 0.9]":">80% and <90%", "(0.9, 1.0]":">90% and <100%", "(1.0, 2.0]":">100%"}

t_df["Ranges"] = t_df["Ranges"].map(lambda x : mydict[str(x)])
```

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: t_df["Ranges"].map( mydict)

Comment: Yep, I was just using lambda's it is more like an habit..!!

Comment: Below worked :

` t_df["Ranges"] = t_df["Ranges"].map(lambda x : mydict[str(x)]) `

Comment: Good catch, I was using `str` ranges for trying out the code.

Comment: Sorry, I had to accept @Jezrael answer as the solution not only he/she provided a solution but right away knew how i got the ranges.

Comment: NP, we all are here to share the knowledge and help each other, upvotes and accepting are nothing considered to the fact we are able to share some information.. Happy Coding..!!

Comment: I'd prefer `t_df["Ranges"].map(mydict.get)`